# Java и нативные методы

Tags: jni, java

Какие есть способы вызвать нативные методы, кроме JNA, JNI, JACOB?

Comment: Между тем, все способы базируются на JNI.

Comment: cy6erGn0m, а как найти вызов нативных методов в коде? я искал поиском по исходниках слов native, jna, jni, load, loadLibrary, имя библиотеки, которая дергается, и ничего не нашлось. Я уже в отчаянии, пытаясь понять как работает код. Видел классы, наследующиеся от awt.Robot, только они вызываются рефлексией. Можно ли вызвать java код из с++, при этом не внояс изменений на java стороне?

Comment: Да, можно. Любой публичный метод можно просто взять и вызвать. Ну... может не совсем просто, но можно. А вот наоборот, то слово `native` обязательно есть. Тот же `awt.Roboot` должен вызывать нативные методы (реализация интерфейса `RobotPeer`, если быть более точным).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Еще можно упомянуть про [**bridj,**](http://code.google.com/p/bridj) который позиционируется как `JNA` с дополнительными фичами.
- Сам не применял, но раздел [**Working Features**](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/wiki/CurrentState#Working_features) выглядит очень даже неплохо в сравнении с [**Known Limitations.**](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/wiki/CurrentState#Known_limitations)